# Wrong S3 Authentication with Paw App

Tags: paw-app

End device: EMC ECS, 
Protocol: AWS S3

I'm trying to authenticate with my Python script and construct the same request using Paw.

**Python** with **boto** works just fine.
The primitive code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

accessKeyId = 'objuser'
secretKey = 'spl4vDHl11H7uW/683WZCoYrle03Bn1hd42gy8bd'
host = '10.10.10.10'
port = 9020

conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,
                    aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
                    host=host,
                    port=port,
                    calling_format='boto.s3.connection.ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat',
                    is_secure=False)

print conn.get_all_buckets()
```

Correct headers are accepted by the S3 server

```
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 07:38:34 GMT 
Authorisation: AWS obtuser:Gi/qcdbyYcVMdI9EkdORPMx2wbo=
```

Next I re-create the same request with Paw but get wrong headers:

```
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 07:38:34 GMT
Authorisation: AWS obtuser:/znFNFviqD5fw3t1oWUwBQ8B5M4=
```

Of course it is rejected by the S3 server.

In Paw I use Authorisation header with standard "***S3 Amazon S3 Authorisation Header***" dynamic value. **AWS Access Key ID** and **Secret Access key ID** are the same as in the script (triple checked).

According to the ECS documentation, S3 Authentication follows [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) So signature is based on the standard HMAC-SHA1.
I expect that the same method is used by Paw.

Could you please advice what is potential reason why Paw doesn't create correct Authorisation header and how to fix that?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry for typo      obtuser = objuser

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for the very late answer!* I've just tested this again myself, using our AWS account, and for example, I've been able to list all our S3 buckets easily, see this screenshot:

[image: Amazon S3 list buckets with Paw]

It seems like it's probably an issue related to the way the Authorization header has been configured, or an invalid character being inserted in the URL field. (A screenshot would help to see what can be wrong)

Comment: Hello Micha. 
Thank you for your answer.

I’m getting access to S3 compatible solution, not Amazon.
It doesn’t work if I generate S3 authentication with Paw. But is works fine when I generate auth token with the script and use it in Paw.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! We have a known issue with non-Amazon implementation of S3, this should get resolved in a future bugfix release. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Using Paw v3.0.16 and "Amazon S3 Authorisation Header" dynamic value, SignatureDoesNotMatch error occurred with this URL.

`GET https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket123/sub456/some789.json`

And it works well with this URL.

`GET https://bucket123.s3.amazonaws.com/sub456/some789.json`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html